# ionic cannot create project

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cmd

### I keep getting this ERROR  while creating new ionic project.

#### There was no issue in my internet connection!

ionic start test1 blank

```
    $ ionic start test1 blank
    √ Creating directory .\test1 - done!
    [INFO] Fetching app base
    (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
    × Downloading - failed!
    Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

or this

```
env export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Comment: command prompt.  2nd will work  only for linux/mac. for window u can add in environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Run  command

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

before

```
ionic start
```

Comment: Did you try reinstalling ionic?